# failing to add latest 3.2.4 npgsql nuget

Tags: npgsql

Adding to my vs2015 update 3 installation. To a brand new console project.

> Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'Npgsql.3.2.4'
>   with respect to project 'ConsoleApplication4', targeting
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2' Attempting to resolve dependencies for
>   package 'Npgsql.3.2.4' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest' Resolving
>   actions to install package 'Npgsql.3.2.4' Resolved actions to install
>   package 'Npgsql.3.2.4' Adding package
>   'System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.4.3.0' to folder
>   'c:\users\paul.pmdev\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication4\packages' Added package
>   'System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.4.3.0' to folder
>   'c:\users\paul.pmdev\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication4\packages' Added package
>   'System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.4.3.0' to 'packages.config'
>   Successfully installed 'System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions 4.3.0' to
>   ConsoleApplication4 Adding package 'Npgsql.3.2.4' to folder
>   'c:\users\paul.pmdev\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication4\packages' Added package
>   'Npgsql.3.2.4' to folder 'c:\users\paul.pmdev\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication4\packages' Install failed. Rolling
>   back... Package 'Npgsql.3.2.4 : System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions
>   [4.3.0, )' does not exist in project 'ConsoleApplication4' Removed
>   package 'System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.4.3.0' from
>   'packages.config' Removing package 'Npgsql.3.2.4 :
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions [4.3.0, )' from folder
>   'c:\users\paul.pmdev\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication4\packages' Removed package
>   'Npgsql.3.2.4 : System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions [4.3.0, )' from
>   folder 'c:\users\paul.pmdev\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication4\packages' Removing package
>   'System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.4.3.0' from folder
>   'c:\users\paul.pmdev\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication4\packages' Removed package
>   'System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.4.3.0' from folder
>   'c:\users\paul.pmdev\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication4\packages' Failed to add reference to
>   'System.Collections'. Please make sure that it is in the Global
>   Assembly Cache.

Comment: Confirmed. Same probllem here.

Comment: This has been fixed. See answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug logged for this on the npgsql issue tracker:

https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/1604

This is now fixed in 3.2.4.1 available on [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql/).